# How to get input character based on keyboard state in Java?

Tags: java, input, keyboard, char

I have an array which represents the current state of keyboard (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> is up, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is down)

And I need to read Unicode character when the state changes. 
How can I get character based on state of the keys?

I need someting which will take `KeyPressed` and `KeyReleased` events on input and generating `KeyTyped` event.

Comment: You can make your class implement KeyboardListener.

Comment: I receiving key states from remote :(

Comment: Please more detail about receiving key states from remote

Comment: I receiving strings like d13 which means Enter is down, than u13 - Enter is up.